# How to test if a program is already installed with BoxStarter script?

Tags: chocolatey, boxstarter

Is there any built-in command to check if a program is already installed, but not by Chocolatey?

```
function Get-InstalledApps {
    if ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
        $regpath = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    }
    else {
        $regpath = @(
            'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        )
    }
    Get-ItemProperty $regpath | .{process{if($_.DisplayName -and $_.UninstallString) { $_ } }} | Select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion, UninstallString |Sort DisplayName
}

function Is-App-Installed($appName) {
    $appToMatch = "*" + $appName + "*"
    $result = Get-InstalledApps | where {$_.DisplayName -like $appToMatch}
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Nothing currently built in, no.  Would some of the licensed features help in what you are trying to achieve? https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize

Comment: Chocolatey will be able to this natively in the future. Right now on the business edition, there is `choco sync`.

Comment: Will have to look at the business features. I think the sync option will be good once the software has been installed. The issue I had was with adobe reader package. Adobe Reader was already installed on the machine and choco install was returning an error code that it was already installed. I guess you could capture that error code as a success.